# How to create flexible replication for XDBC server?

Tags: marklogic

I have a master site, for which replication needs to be generated in the DR site. When I try to create a replica database it is generated as HTTP protocal by default. But, my database is master is a XDBC. Can anyone give some idea to create XDBC replication?

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge Flexible Replication is designed to work with CPF pipelines in either push or pull configuration. It requires running some custom code to make it work properly, and can therefor not run against XDBC servers. The [Flexible Replication Guide](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/flexrep) gives full detail on how to setup both master and slave side.

If you are looking for straight replication, you can look into using [Database Replication](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/database-replication) instead, which does not require any extra App Servers at all if I'm not mistaken.

HTH!

Answer (score 0):

Definitely make sure you look into using [Database Replication](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/database-replication) as a mechanism. It's relatively simple to configure and ideal for DR scenarios. Flex Rep is more ideally suited for more advanced use cases.

It's important to understand that the databases are separate from the application servers. A database can have any number of application servers of any type pointed at them. You're really looking to set up Flex Rep for the database, not for your XDBC server...

With this in mind, your XDBC server on port XXXX will be configured to point to a particular content database. That same content database can have HTTP servers on other ports that point to it.

Flex Rep uses HTTP application servers which you will need to configure according to the documents that grtjn mentioned above. You will still use your XDBC server as you normally do, but the Flex Rep process will use the Flex Rep application servers over HTTP for replicating data. You'll need to further configure your triggers and other aspects of the CPF pipeline to meet your specific goals.